# Count and Joins with Where

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Customer

```
CustomerID Name
4001       John Bob
4002       Joey Markle
4003       Johny Brown
4004       Jessie Black
```

Orders

```
OrderID    Customer   Status
50001      4001       Paid
50002      4002       Paid
50003      4001       Paid
50004      4003       Paid
50005      4001       Paid
50006      4003       Paid
50007      4004       Unpaid
```

I tried this join

```
Select c.Customer, COUNT(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from Customer c
inner join Orders o
on c.Customer = o.Customer
Where o.Status = 'Paid'
Group by c.Customer
```

But here is the result.

```
Customer  TotalOrders
4001      3
4002      1
4003      2
```

The customer with unpaid is not included. How I will include all the customer ?

```
Customer  TotalOrders
4001      3
4002      1
4003      2
4004      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a more complex `left join` in order to only count the `Paid` ones:

```
SELECT c.customerid, count(o.orderid) TotalOrders
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON c.customerid = o.customer AND o.status = 'Paid'
GROUP BY c.customerid
```

Output:

```
| CUSTOMERID | TOTALORDERS |
|------------|-------------|
|       4001 |           3 |
|       4002 |           1 |
|       4003 |           2 |
|       4004 |           0 |
```

See the working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3cbc3/1).

Comment: Isn't status a reserved word in SQl Server? I guess it mght need the [] - brackets around it

Comment: @TGH It doesn't seem to be a reserved word, or at least the fiddle isn't complaining about it. Even if it was it is a trivial fix that the OP could easily perform.

Answer (score 5):

Use a left join

```
Select c.Customer, COUNT(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from Customer c
left join Orders o
on c.Customer = o.Customer
Group by c.Customer
```

Comment: I believe the o.[Status] = 'Paid' field has to be added to the join cirteria

Comment: With your edit, Mosty Mostacho answer fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select c.CustomerId, COUNT(o.OrderID) as TotalOrders
from Customer c
left join Orders o on c.CustomerId = o.Customer and o.[Status] = 'Paid'
Group by c.CustomerId
```

Try the above.

Comment: I made a tweak to the answer